# How can i integrate node.js scripts recorded by appium in protractor tests?

Tags: ios, node.js, protractor, appium, end-to-end

I have an Angular JS application and i want to generate some automatic tests using `ipad simulator`  and `Appium`.
I have the file `conf.js` that contain the configuration and `test.js` that contain my tests with protractor.
How can i integrate the generated scripts in `protractor`?

Thanks.